# How can i login from Axios/Ajax in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, axios

I'm building a Vue SPA where Django will be the backend of the Vue app and will communicate with the frontend only usinsg JSON.

I'm trying to handle authentication now, and i'm trying to login from the Vue app using Axios (i'm using the standard session authentication), the Django backend uses [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), so basically the Vue app should send a POST request to `accounts/login/` which is a Django-Allauth URL in my backend. The problem with my code is that when i send the request with Axios nothing happens, and instead of logging in the response will be HTML instead of a valid response,  Django-Allauth supports AJAX calls so that should not be a problem.

Here is my code:

```
authenticate() {

  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/', {     
        username: 'root',
        password: 'test',
        
    }, {
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': this.csrf_token,
      },
    })

    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    }.bind(this))
},
```

The response is HTML, while this is what i see in the terminal: `[23/Mar/2021 20:04:37] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1607`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `withCredentials` in Axios options so that browser save cookies from AJAX response.

```
authenticate() {

  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/', {     
        username: 'root',
        password: 'test',
        
    }, {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': this.csrf_token,
      },
    })

    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
    }.bind(this))
},
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately i still get an HTML response

Comment: What are the contents of response?

Comment: It's the HTML page that Django allauth renders when i open /accounts/login/ on my browser

Comment: That's expected behavior. What do you want it to respond with?

Comment: I mean, what i'm trying to do is to login from axios but when i try to i don't get logged in and i don't receive any response except for that html, while i should receive an AJAX response

Comment: Alright, if i open the HTML response on my browser there is an error 'this field is required' on both the fields, so i guess i'm not sending username and password properly